# Line break in large formula and error message in align?

Tags: line-breaking, align

I have a very long `align` formula and I do not know how to optimally (that it looks good and is accetable with LaTeX rules) line-break this. Currently I have

```
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)&\approx (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\zeta^{*})+\frac{\pi^{2}\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})}{1+\pi^{2}}\cdot  \mathrm{Var}(\pi)\\ &+ (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\delta^{*}) + \\
2&\times \left[ \pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta^{*}) - (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*})  - \pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\pi)\right]
\end{align*}
```

I tried

```
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Var}(\alpha)&\approx (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\zeta^{*})+\frac{\pi^{2}\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})}{1+\pi^{2}}\cdot  \mathrm{Var}(\pi)\\ &+ (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Var}(\delta^{*}) + \\
2&\times \left[ \pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\pi,\zeta^{*}) - (1+\pi^{2})\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*}) \\ & - \pi\exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})\cdot \mathrm{Cov}(\delta^{*},\pi)\right]
\end{align*}
```

But I get the error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \right.
<template> }
            $}\ifmeasuring@ \savefieldlength@ \fi \set@field \hfil \endtempl...
l.1533 \end{align*}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: You can't use `\left` in one line and `\right` in another; by the way, they aren't necessary in this context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing you can do, is to use the `\hphantom` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*\var{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator*\cov{Cov}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \var(\alpha)
  &\approx (1 + \pi^{2}) \exp(-2\delta^{*} + 2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \var(\zeta^{*})\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + \frac{\pi^{2} \exp(-2\delta^{*} + 2\zeta^{*})}{1 + \pi^{2}} \cdot \var(\pi)\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + (1 + \pi^{2}) \exp(-2\delta^{*} + 2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \var(\delta^{*})\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + 2 \times \bigl[\pi \exp(-2\delta^{*} + 2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \cov(\pi, \zeta^{*})\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx + 2 \times \bigl[} - (1 + \pi^{2}) \exp(-2\delta^{*} + 2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \cov(\delta^{*}, \zeta^{*})\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx + 2 \times \bigl[} - \pi \exp(-2\delta^{*} + 2\zeta^{*}) \cdot \cov(\delta^{*}, \pi)\bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

On Barbara's note: egreg has explained why one needs `\bigl` and `\bigr` intead of `\left` and `\right`.

**Comment**

If you want to save a few keystrokes, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*\var{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator*\cov{Cov}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \var(\alpha)
  &\approx (1 + \pi^2) \exp(-2\delta^* + 2\zeta^*) \cdot \var(\zeta^*)\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + \frac{\pi^2 \exp(-2\delta^* + 2\zeta^*)}{1 + \pi^2} \cdot \var(\pi)\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + (1 + \pi^2) \exp(-2\delta^* + 2\zeta^*) \cdot \var(\delta^*)\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + 2 \times \bigl[\pi \exp(-2\delta^* + 2\zeta^*) \cdot \cov(\pi, \zeta^*)\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx + 2 \times \bigl[} - (1 + \pi^2) \exp(-2\delta^* + 2\zeta^*) \cdot \cov(\delta^*, \zeta^*)\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx + 2 \times \bigl[} - \pi \exp(-2\delta^* + 2\zeta^*) \cdot \cov(\delta^*, \pi)\bigr]
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you might explain why you used `\bigl` and `\bigr`.  (very nice alignment.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Comment added. (And thank you for the compilment.)

Answer (score 5):

You can reduce the size of the equation and some repetitive typing by this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator*\var{Var}
\DeclareMathOperator*\cov{Cov}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \var(\alpha)
  &\approx (1+\pi^{2})A\cdot \var(\zeta^{*})
   + \frac{\pi^{2}A}{1+\pi^{2}}\cdot \var(\pi)
   + (1+\pi^{2})A\cdot \var(\delta^{*})\\
  &\hphantom{{}\approx} + 2 \times \bigl[ \pi A\cdot \cov(\pi,\zeta^{*})
   - (1+\pi^{2})A\cdot \cov(\delta^{*},\zeta^{*})
   - \pi A\cdot \cov(\delta^{*},\pi)\bigr]
\end{align*}
where 
\[
    A = \exp(-2\delta^{*}+2\zeta^{*})
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]